# Change schema name strategy in confluent Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am using confluent Kafka and schema registry and I cannot figure out a way to have custom schema name in python. From this [blog](https://karengryg.io/2018/08/18/multi-schemas-in-one-kafka-topic/) I got how to do it in Java, but do not have any idea what the equivalent of:

```
properties.setProperty("value.subject.name.strategy", TopicRecordNameStrategy.class.getName());
```

would be. Adding the property `'key.subject.name.strategy': 'io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy'` in the `AvroProducer()` does not help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python client doesn't currently expose this property.

See, https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/477 and linked issues

Comment: I suppose you could manually register the schema subject and use the regular `Producer` class

Answer (score 0):

I think it's equivalent with

```py
import confluent_kafka

serializer_config = {
    'auto.register.schemas': False,  # decide by yourself
    'subject.name.strategy': confluent_kafka.schema_registry.topic_record_subject_name_strategy,
}
```

And then use this config to initialize an `AvroSerializer`, which could be used to initialize a `SerializingProducer`.

I use `confluent-kafka` with version 2.3.0